# Mathematical step with complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

There is a mathematical step in the book that I'm using to study Microelectronics that I can't understand:

How can

$$ \frac{1}{a+(\beta+1)(r_e+\frac{1}{j\omega C_E})}$$ become

$$\frac{1}{a+(\beta+1)r_e} \frac {j\omega}{j\omega+[\frac{1}{C_E (r_e+ \frac{a}{\beta+1})}]}$$

(j is the imaginary unit and you can consider the other letters as constants)

I have tried some different ways but with no result. Could you help me?

Comment: Does the expression $[\frac 1{C_E(r_e+\frac a{\beta+1})}]$ have a special meaning due to the brackets?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}\frac{1}{a+(\beta+1)(r_e+\frac{1}{j\omega C_E})} & = \frac{1}{a+(\beta+1)r_e+(\beta+1)\frac{1}{j\omega C_E}} \\ & = \frac{1}{\biggl[a+(\beta+1)r_e\biggr]\biggr(1+\frac{(\beta+1)}{a+(\beta+1)r_e}\frac{1}{j\omega C_E}\biggr)} \\& = \frac{1}{a+(\beta+1)r_e}\frac{1}{1+\frac{(\beta+1)}{a+(\beta+1)r_e}\frac{1}{j\omega C_E}}  \\& = \frac{1}{a+(\beta+1)r_e}\frac{j\omega}{j\omega+\frac{(\beta+1)}{a+(\beta+1)r_e}\frac{1}{ C_E}} \\& = \frac{1}{a+(\beta+1)r_e}\frac{j\omega}{j\omega+\frac{1}{\frac{a}{1+\beta}+r_e}\frac{1}{ C_E}}   \end{align*}

(To obtain the fourth equality multiply the numerator and the denominator by $jw$)